# How do make snippets work for Ruby On Rails in Textmate 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate2

On a fresh install of Textmate2, you used to be able to type `hm<tab>` while editing in a model and it would type out a whole `has_many` line for you, but now it just types a tab. All of the text-completion seems broken. The ones from Ruby are still working (`def<tab>` creates a method block with the name selected, for instance).

I noticed that the "Ruby on Rails" bundle wasn't enabled by default anymore, but I fixed that and the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

The snippets still work, but you have to make sure that the language mode is set to "Ruby On Rails" in the bottom status bar, otherwise they won't trigger.

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'm aware of the context modes, have it set to Ruby on Rails, and the commands are showing up under the gear menu. This a new install of TM2 on new install of El Capitan.