# Textmate 2 Ruby on Rails bundle: Some snippets no longer work on macOS Big Sur (all released versions), e.g. hm \tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate, macos-big-sur

On a fresh install of Big Sur (updated all the way to 11.3.1) with a Rails 6 project I noticed that some snippets will not autocomplete (e.g. hm → tab). This happened also on all previous releases of Big Sur. Catalina with a Rails 6 project on the same machine has no issue at all.

When I boot into Big Sur (11.2.1 / 11.3.1) in a Rails 6 project or any file with type set to "Ruby on Rails" and the "Ruby on Rails" bundle installed, no snippet with scope meta.rails.model will tab-complete. I can run them from the bundle menu, however.

The issue presents itself the same as this question [How do make snippets work for Ruby On Rails in Textmate 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562455/how-do-make-snippets-work-for-ruby-on-rails-in-textmate-2), which is fairly old and to which there seems to be no resolution.

I found these instructions on coderwall https://coderwall.com/p/b6j9mw/fix-textmate-code-completion-for-rails-4-models, however they did nothing for me. I quit and restarted textmate, uninstalled, reinstalled, cleaned out the library, however, nothing seems to work.

Anybody ever solved something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a tip on #textmates IRC channel.

Pressing control-shift-P in the file that is misbehaving shows you information about the current scope. After that I re-set the language to ruby-on-rails (it had changed to ruby, maybe by pressing the keys above, maybe independently).

Now it works.